# How to chromecast from android phone to tv

Tags: video-streaming, chromecast, google-cast

I want to stream home videos from android phone to TV without uploading them to the web first. For this i want to integrate chrome cast in my android application. But i have no idea how to do it. If anybody knows how to do it in android studio. Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a web server embedded in your Android app so that it can serve the images (as if the image is in the cloud) and then obtain the URL of the image (as it is exposed by your embedded web server) and use that as the url for the media. Note that your video needs to be mp4 for this case to work since adaptive streams need CORS and require https.